# polkadot explorer getting stuck while using utility and sudo pallet from extrinsics

Tags: polkadot, extrinsic, runtime-upgrade, blockchain, sudo

I am  trying to do a runtime upgrade of my blockchain that is `layer 0` chain  running  on version `polkado-v0.9.36` . I also have `(ethereum virtual machine` integrated to it ).

When I do runtime upgrade of blockchain through `page-sudo` everthing works fine but when I try to do runtime upgrade from `extrinsics` call  using `pallet_sudo` the polkadot explorer gets stucked and I have to reopen explorer to continue using it, and same is also happening while using `pallet_utility` from `extrinsics` calls.

The other pallets are working fine in `extrinsics` , it is happening for only these two pallets. Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong here and how I can solve this.

I am attaching a screenshot below of my page getting stuck and asking me to exit it.

---

[image: explorer stucked here]

Comment: Could you please verify within your runtime that 'pallet-sudo' is not set at index 255?

Answer (score 2):

This is a performance issue. I've encountered it before as well. What I did was open a new browser and try using different wallets. It appears that signing a WASM significantly affects performance.

Comment: In my case it was due to the numbering issue for these pallets in runtime